# How to update the current login user

Tags: dml, user-record, dmlexception

I have a custom field over my user object. And I want to update this user by the contact id from apex. How can i update the user record in salesforce. Because when I trying to update the field of current login user I am getting an error

> DML currently not allowed

please help me to get the solution over this issue.

Comment: This error normally occurs when trying to do DML in constructor. Is it you case?